# iconv() error when running Statamic (Laravel) SEO Pro plugin with php:fpm-alpine docker image

Tags: laravel, docker, alpine-linux, statamic

When using Statamic 3.2 / Laravel 8 and the Statamic SEO Pro 2.3 plugin, I am getting the following error on ever page of the site:

`iconv(): Wrong encoding, conversion from &quot;UTF-8&quot; to &quot;UTF-8//IGNORE&quot; is not allowed`

My environment is based on the `php:8-fpm-alpine` docker image.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to a compatibility issue with the `libiconv` package in Alpine Linux.

References to the issue which has been known for a while:

https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/12328

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/240

A workaround until a more permanent fix is made available, in the PHP dockerfile:

`RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/ gnu-libiconv=1.15-r3`

`ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so`